# SQL Melhoria de procedimento

Tags: sql-server

Gostaria de saber se haveria uma maneira para melhorar um código que fiz na mão no SQL...
Eu tenho uma tabela da seguinte Tabela

```
    Chave identificadora - DataProduto - Preço - Marca
    Lanche - Pao/presunto - 01/01/2017 - 5.90 - McDonalds
    Lanche - Pao/presunto - 01/01/2017 - 5.90 - McDonalds
    Lanche - Pao/presunto - 01/02/2017 - 5.90 - McDonalds
    Jantar- Pao/presunto - 01/01/2017 - 5.90 - Burger King
    Almoço- Pao/presunto - 01/01/2017 - 5.90 - KFC
```

Sendo a primeira linha meu cabeçalho eu preciso agrupar isso e transformar as marcas em colunas então eu fiz a seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT [Chave identificadora], DataProduto,SUM(McDonalds)McDonalds, SUM(BurgerKing)BurgerKing,SUM(KFC)[KFC]

 FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT [Chave identificadora], DataProduto,
CASE WHEN MARCA = 'McDonalds' THEN Preço ELSE 0 END as McDonalds,
CASE WHEN MARCA = 'Burger King' THEN Preço ELSE 0 END as BurgerKing,
CASE WHEN MARCA = 'KFC' THEN Preço ELSE 0 END as KFC
from Tabela_Produtos
) AS A  


group by chaveidentificadora,dataproduto

Order by dataproduto
```

Isso vai me retornar exatamente

```
Chave - Data - McDonalds - BurgerKing - KFC
Lanche - 01/01/2017 - 11.80 - 5.90 - 5.90
Lanche - 01/02/2017 - 5.90 - 0.00 - 0.00
```

Ou seja, está correto ! porém  nesse caso eu escrevi 3 marcas (bk, kfc e mc) se caso eu tivesse 500 marcas eu teria que escrever na mão. Minha dúvida seria, teria uma maneira de melhorar isso fazendo com que idependente de 1,5,10mil registros eu executo um certo código/procedure que deixe isso pronto ?
(peço desculpas caso eu não tenha sido claro o suficiente)

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: O que você precisa é montar um PIVOT dinâmico, transformando cada valor da coluna "Marca" em novas colunas. O truque é fazer uma consulta para guardar todos os valores possíveis da coluna "Marca" e depois montar o PIVOT em uma query dinâmica com EXECUTE. Aqui tem um passo a passo bem didático: http://vladimirrech.blogspot.com.br/2014/02/pivot-dinamico-com-sql-server.html

Comment: @VanderleiAdriano mas no caso eu não terei que informar todos as marcas no IN do pivot ? se eu tiver 1000 registros vou colocar IN([bk],[mc]...) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O truque é fazer uma consulta para guardar todos os valores possíveis da coluna "Marca" primeiro:

```
  declare @cols nvarchar(max)

  set @cols = stuff((
        select distinct ',' + MARCA
        from Tabela_Produtos
        for xml path('')), 1,1, '');
```

e depois montar o PIVOT em uma query dinâmica com EXECUTE:

```
  declare @query as nvarchar(max)

  set @query='SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT Preco, Marca
     FROM   Tabela_Produtos
  ) AS t
  PIVOT (
          SUM(Preco)
          FOR Marca IN ( ' + @cols + ' ) 
        ) as P;';

  execute(@query)
```

Você pode adicionar outras colunas e GROUP BY conforme a necessidade. Aqui tem uma explicação e passo a passo bem didática: [Pivot Dinâmico com SQL](http://vladimirrech.blogspot.com.br/2014/02/pivot-dinamico-com-sql-server.html)